# Two if statements in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following code, I want to read the parameters from the link and display them. I used two separate if statements to check each parameter. The problem is it only reads the first if statement and discards the second one (does not check the second parameter):

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  if (request.method == 'GET') {
    var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    // if parameter is provided
    if (queryData.name) {
      response.end('Hello ' + queryData.name + '\n');
    } else {
      response.end("Hello World\n");
    }
    if (queryData.age) {
      response.end('Your age is ' + queryData.age + '\n');
    } else {
      response.end("No age provided\n");
    }
  }
});
// Listen on port 3000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1 (localhost)
server.listen(8081);
```

The link is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/start?name=john&age=25
```

Comment: response.end will end the response, thats why the second statement does not apply if the fist one succeded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `response.end`. Instead use `response.write` and add an `response.end()` after both if-statements.

See docs: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback

Answer (score 1):

Try `response.write` in the first `if` block.